# How can i use my existing cakephp based project users to work with XMPP ejabberd chat application

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, converse.js

I have a cakephp2.3 based project with table name "user_master".

I am using ejabberd chat application and ejabberd user table name is "user".

I am using convers.js client.

Now i am facing problem to use my existing project user with XMPP ejabberd to authenticate , send friend request , chat with friends.

I tried using external auth but it allowed me to login even if I add wrong credentials on ejabberd server using http://localhost:5280/admin link.

I am using Ubuntu and i have add all types of setting.It is working fine if i use it as stand alone application but when i want use it for my existing user it stopped working.

Ejabberd Server : http://localhost:5280/admin

External authentication configuration in "ejabberd.cfg" file.

```
{auth_method, external}.
{extauth_program, "/etc/ejabberd/auth.php"}.
```

External authentication file "auth.php".

```
 <?php 
        require 'ejabberd_external_auth.php';
        class Auth extends EjabberdExternalAuth {
            protected function authenticate($user, $server, $password) {
                $stmt = $this->db()->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? ");
                $stmt->execute(array($user, $password));
                if($stmt->rowCount() >= 0 )
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            protected function exists($user, $server) {
                $stmt = $this->db()->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ? ");
                $stmt->execute(array($user));
                if($stmt->rowCount() >= 0 )
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=ejabberd;host=localhost', 'root', 'root');
        new Auth($pdo, 'auth.log');
```

Thanks in advance